# Oracle SQL - Issue updating multiple rows with json_table (Oracle 12C [12.1])

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I'm trying to update my table using a JSON as follows:

```
[
  {
    "NEWDATAPATH": "/user/data/2019/10/28/data-1.zip",
    "CATID": -1
  },
  {
    "NEWDATAPATH": "/user/data/2019/10/28/data-2.zip",
    "CATID": -2
  },
  {
    "NEWDATAPATH": "/user/data/2019/10/28/data-3.zip",
    "CATID": -3
  }
]
```

With the following query:

```
UPDATE IMGTABLE v
SET (DELDATE, DATAPATH) = (SELECT v.EXTENDDATE, j.NEWDATAPATH
                           FROM json_table(Details, '$[*]' COLUMNS(CATID NUMBER PATH '$.CATID',
                                                                   NEWDATAPATH VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.NEWDATAPATH')) j
                           WHERE v.CATID = j.CATID)                                             
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM json_table(Details, '$[*]' COLUMNS(CATID NUMBER PATH '$.CATID')) j
              WHERE v.CATID = j.CATID);
```

The issue I am having with the above code is it will only update the first row (CATID = -1) and NULL out the column values of interest for the remaining matched rows.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
CATID |    DELDATE  |    EXTENDATE| DATAPATH                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 -1   |   10-28-2019|   10-28-2020|  "/user/data/2019/10/28/data-1.zip"
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 -2   |   (null)    |   10-28-2020|  (null)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 -3   |   (null)    |   10-28-2020|  (null)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Where is `Details` coming from? Is it a column in `IMGTABLE`?

Comment: Sorry I should of specified. Details is "IN CLOB" for a procedure which holds the JSON

Comment: When I try to replicate it in a PLSQL block, your update statement works fine (on Oracle 12.2.0.1). I'm not sure if it's a 12.1 issue, or if it's something else in your code that we can't see.

Comment: Thanks it possibly could be it, i'll have to try again once our Oracle has been updated.